# Parse JSON result and check for specifing string in status

Tags: c#

What is the most efficient apprach to read such `JSON file`. To be honest what i need to take from that `JSON` is the distance. Inside `elements node` there could be either one or multiple items containing `distance and duration`. I need to `SUM` all of that values from each `element`'s node: `distance-text`. For example: `324 km` (`distance in kilemeters`). I shown below 3 examples. How can i do that?

Morover in last example if request is bad there could be something like `"NOT_FOUND"` (or something else besides `"OK"`). If in any `"status"` there would be something diffrent than `"OK"` at east in one i should get `throw Exception()`.

**JSON response example 1:**

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Długa 50, 05-075 Warszawa, Slovakia" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Wilenska 2, Zabrze, Slovakia" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "324 km",
                  "value" : 323619
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 hours 16 mins",
                  "value" : 11776
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

**In this case i should calculate as: 324**

**JSON response example 2: (There could be more elements like here)**

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Długa 50, 05-075 Warszawa, Slovakia" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Wilenska 2, Zabrze, Slovakia" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "324 km",
                  "value" : 323619
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 hours 16 mins",
                  "value" : 11776
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "192 km",
                  "value" : 191950
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "2 hours 26 mins",
                  "value" : 8732
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

**In this case i should calculate as: 516**

**JSON response example 3: (with some statuses diffrent than "OK")**

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "", "", "" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
            },
            {
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "ERR" 
}
```

**In this case i should get Exception**

Comment: Q: I'm curious: why "Slovakia", and not "Poland"?  To answer your question: you *DON'T* want to "check for a string".  You want to add Json.Net (a NuGet package)  to your project, and call `JsonConvert.Deserialize()`: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek4DeserializingJSONWithJsonNET.aspx

Comment: @paulsm4 I have some generator for other purposes but it's not the case for that topic.

Comment: Use NewtonSoft library. You can call JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(). It would create an object of your JSON that you can loop through a foreach. Then just add up each "distance" from this object to a new variable if the status is "OK", otherwise throw an Exception.

Comment: @ThomasH can you post the answer? Don;t know how to get those values (still trying)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use https://json2csharp.com/ to generate C# classes based on your json structure.

then install nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Json.Net/

then you can try the following code:

```
var sampleJson = @"{


""destination_addresses"" : [ ""Długa 50, 05-075 Warszawa, Slovakia"" ],
   ""origin_addresses"" : [ ""Wilenska 2, Zabrze, Slovakia"" ],
   ""rows"" : [
      {
         ""elements"" : [
            {
               ""distance"" : {
                  ""text"" : ""324 km"",
                  ""value"" : 323619
               },
               ""duration"" : {
                  ""text"" : ""3 hours 16 mins"",
                  ""value"" : 11776
               },
               ""status"" : ""OK""
            },
            {
               ""distance"" : {
                  ""text"" : ""192 km"",
                  ""value"" : 191950
               },
               ""duration"" : {
                  ""text"" : ""2 hours 26 mins"",
                  ""value"" : 8732
               },
               ""status"" : ""OK""
            },
         ]
      }
   ],
   ""status"" : ""OK""
}";

    var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(sampleJson);
    if (obj.status != "OK")
    {
        throw new Exception($"Status is: {obj.status}");
    }

    if (obj.rows.Any(r => r.elements.Any(e => e.status != "OK")))
    {
        throw new Exception("some of the elements status is not ok");
    }

    var allDistanceText = obj.rows?.Select(e => e.elements).SelectMany(e => e.Select(d => d.distance?.text));
    int sum = allDistanceText.Select(dt => dt?.Replace("km", "")?.Trim())
        .Sum(dt =>
        {
            if (int.TryParse(dt, out int results))
            {
                return results;
            }
            return 0;
        });
    sum.Dump();
```

Comment: I get null on var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonstring); I provided from my examples.

Comment: Which json sample are you trying?

Comment: all is good, thank you.